# Wrong value gets stored in the list

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

This should store [1,2,3,4,5] in the list but it stores [1,1,1,1,1] instead:

```
l=[0]*5
for x in range(5):
    y=1
    l[x] = y
    y+=1
print (l)
```

Comment: you are initializing `y=1` inside for loop for every run. Take it outside loop.

Comment: I am not sure this question was closed with the correct duplicate in mind; the error had not much to do with the immutability of ints; it is a typical new programmer question, and if SO can't answer, where can they turn to for help with this sort of mistakes?

Comment: the duplicate closure was a mistake. But there isn't much to answer there. For me it looks very much like a typo... Anil_M solved this in comments...

Comment: Note that it's much more pythonic to do `l = list(range(1, 6))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you must place `y = 1` before entering the `for` loop:

```
my_list = [0] * 5
y = 1
for x in range(5):
    my_list[x] = y
    y += 1
print(my_list)
```

I changed the name of your list to `my_list`; using `l` is a source of confusion with `1`...

Comment: yeah thanks thats a noob error